# PHP sqlsrv_query dynamic order by clause

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

(Note that this is for MSSQL, not MYSQL)

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE SeriesID = ? ORDER BY ? ?";
   $result = $conn->getData($query, array($seriesID,$sortBy,$sortOrder));
```

I don't see any errors, but no results are returned.

When I don't have the ORDER BY portion, it works. It's the second and third question marks that kill it.

$conn->getData() is calling sqlsrv_query() function...

There is a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857039/php-sqlsrv-sorting-with-parameter-of-prepared-statement/28331682#28331682) which I answered with a workaround, but I'd like to find out why this doesn't work as I think it should.

Comment: You're missing a `,` I guess.

Comment: ^ that's what I was thinking also.

Comment: Unless the second one is supposed to be ASC or DESC.

Comment: ORDER BY field [ASC|DESC] is the syntax here.